# How to override Ionic standard colours?

Tags: ionic-framework

For my ionic app, I am trying to update the energized colour to the following:

```
$energized: #FFC0A9 !default;
```

I updated ionic.app.scss in the /scss directory and restarted the app using ionic serve. However the colour hasn't been updated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sass (http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html), did you execute "$gulp sass" before running the application?